# Repeating text inside getview's textview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am implementing a custom ListView which has some text fields (for titles) and below that a textview when clicked, it opens an Alert Dialog that shows the list of options and when user select any option, the TextView text is set to that option. Up to here all is working good but when I scroll the listview the values selected in that textview is just changed to some other values. Please help me solving this problem how to make this view correct. For this I am showing two images below

First Image in where I have selected the first row text as one and left the other row untouched.

[image]

And this is the second Image which shows after scroll down and scroll back the first row textview is just changed and also the other is filled with text even I have not selected any value for them.

[image]

Here is my MainActivity Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    Controller control ; 
    ArrayList<MyDetails> detail;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_speed);

        detail=(ArrayList<MyDetails>) control.Table_Details.Data();


        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_layout);
        MyBaseAdapter adapter = new MyBaseAdapter(this, detail);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void showDialog(final TextView option,final CharSequence[] items){
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
       builder.setTitle("Make your selection");
       builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
               // Do something with the selection
               option.setText(items[item]);
           }
       });
       AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
       alert.show();
    }
}
```

And here is my Adapter code

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


    ArrayList<MyDetails> list;
    Context context ;
    public MyBaseAdapter(Context con, ArrayList<MyDetails> detail) {
        this.context = con;
        this.list =detail ;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(view == null)
        {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout, null);
        }

        TextView title= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        final TextView data = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data);
        title.setText(list.get(position).title());

         final CharSequence[] items = {
                    "One", "tow", "three", "four", "six"
            };

        data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ((MainActivity) context).showDialog(data,items);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

Any help will highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of using `data.setOnClickListener` you should implement the `OnItemClickListener` to deliminate what item you are clicking and need to change accordingly.

Comment: @Tukajo this is a good information you posted thanks. Can you please help me with some code example to solve the above problem.

Comment: try following along with this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue should occured by finding the id's `TextView` each time you are calling `getView()` in the `Adapter`. I might be wrong but I think you should try to get the view while you inflate the layout's item and (*after*) set the text to it.

Furthermore, using a [`ViewHolder`](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) might be better for performance, it allows to call `findViewById` only once and avoid to recall it each time `getView()` is called when you scroll the list.
So, try to use a `ViewHolder` as follows:

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // init the viewholder 
    protected class ViewHolder() {
        TextView title, data;
    }  

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // create the var viewholder
        ViewHolder holder;
        // init the row once if it's null
        if(view == null) {
            // inflate the row and find views only the first time
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                       context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout, null);
            // create the viewholder
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            // attach views with viewholder
            holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.data = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data);
            // set a tag to retrieve it later
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // reuse the row by getting the previous tag
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // set the text to the views attached
        title.setText(list.get(position).title());
        ...
        return view;
    }
}
```

Also, as *Tukajo* said in comments below the question, it might be better to set an [`ItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) to the whole row instead of setting an `OnClickListener` inside it.
Therefore, after `setAdapter()` in the activity, do as follows to call the `Dialog`:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Show the dialog...
        // (Not sure but you can try to retrieve the TextView like this:)   
        showDialog( ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.data)) , items);
        // Then 'items' array needs to be in the Activity, outside the Adapter
    }
});
```

Hope this will solve your issue.